# AWS EKS service IP from VPC Subnet

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

In short: I want to connect from my EC2 instance to Redis located in EKS.

Description:
I have VPC with 2 subnets. My EKS and EC2 are using the same, this VPC.

Problem:
I have installed Redis with helm with default values.
I see, that the pod (and all other pods in K8s) is using IPs from my VPC (`10.111.x.x`)
This IP is accessible from EC2, but I cant use it, because during pod restart it will get different IP.
My Redis also have service, and I want to use this service. But for some reason, my service (and all other services) looks like have cluster internal IP: `172.20.x.x` (`type: ClusterIP`).

How it is possible to use IP from my VPC / subnets?

I know, that I can use type LoadBalancer, but I dont want to create additional AWS resource for that.

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Using service type as nodePort might help you in this case as you dont want to use loadbalancer. Expose your service using a nodePort and then access it using NodeIP:NodePort